# stop bash from printing invalid unicode sequences

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, unicode

Doing `echo -e "\uDDAA"` (which is not a valid utf-8 codepoint) in bash, prints `���`.

How can I make it not print anything if its not a valid codepoint?

what im trying to do is add in front of all codepoints in [NamesList.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt), the character it represents. right now i have it as

```bsh
sed -e 's/\<\([0-9A-F]\{4,6\}\)\>/\\U\1 \1/g' < NamesList.txt | while read -r line;do echo -e "$line"; done | sponge NamesList.txt
```

If theres a better way of doing it that completely goes around the issue then please post that solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create those sequences in the first place. This will print spaces for control characters (`\pC`) and give the marks (`\pM`) a space to ride on:

```
perl -CO -pe 's{^([0-9A-F]+)\b}{$x=$1,$c=chr hex $x;if($c=~/\pC/){$c=" "}elsif($c=~/\pM/){$c=" $c"}"$c $x"}e' NamesList.txt
```

(use `-i NamesList.txt` if you want to edit the file in place)

See [Unicode Character Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). Surrogates, bidi marks and other controls that you do NOT want displayed are in the category "Other" (`\pC`). Accents and other combining marks are in the category "Marks" (`\pM`).